# Move fancy header down without moving body of article

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, article

I am using the fancy header package in an article class (see preamble snippet):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=15mm, right=15mm, top=15mm, bottom=16mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,mathrsfs,accents}

\pagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[l]{\scriptsize{Text to move down}}
```

The geometry package gives me the correct margins for the body of the article, however, I am finding the header is too high. I would like to move the header lower without affecting the placement of the body of the article.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Set `headsep`. For example `\usepackage[left=15mm, right=15mm, top=15mm, bottom=16mm, headsep= 2mm]{geometry}`

Comment: @SimonDispa, is there similarly a `footsep` option for the footer?

Comment: Try `footskip= 4mm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `heightrounded` option to `geometry` so as to ensure an integral number of lines. If you remove `\scriptsize` (by the way, it's not a command taking an argument), you receive the warning

```
Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt):
(fancyhdr)                Make it at least 13.59999pt, for example:
(fancyhdr)                \setlength{\headheight}{13.59999pt}.
(fancyhdr)                You might also make \topmargin smaller to compensate:

(fancyhdr)                \addtolength{\topmargin}{-1.59999pt}.
```

Don't follow the advice about `\topmargin` and add

```
headheight=13.6pt
```

to the options to `geometry`, unless you plan to use a smaller font size in the header.

Now you can change also `headsep` and `footskip` in order to move the header and footer nearer to the text block. If you add the `verbose` option to `geometry`

```
\usepackage[
  left=15mm,
  right=15mm,
  top=15mm,
  bottom=16mm,
  heightrounded,% <--- added, use it
  showframe,% <--- just for debugging
  verbose,% <--- just for debugging
]{geometry}
```

you will see in the console output and in the log file

```
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: heightrounded showframe
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(42.67912pt, 528.93675pt, 42.67912pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(42.67912pt, 706.76646pt, 45.5244pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=528.93675pt
* \textheight=704.60031pt
* \oddsidemargin=-29.59087pt
* \evensidemargin=-29.59087pt
* \topmargin=-66.59087pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=11.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=59.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)
```

so you now know that the value of `\headsep` is 25pt. Reduce it, say to 16pt or whatever you see fit. For `\footskip` you could use 20pt. Now the example.

[image]

When you're done, remove the extra keys for debugging.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the tips on debugging!